# PlantUML - How to define a Flow Final Node in an activity diagram with the new syntax?

Tags: uml, plantuml

In PlantUML, for activity diagrams in the new syntax, how can I define a "Flow Final Node" (a non-filled circle with inner cross) instead of an "Activity Final Node" (an filled black circle, surrounded by a non-filled black circle => `stop`)? Thanks in advance.

here's how they differ:

[image: here's how they differ]

I've searched the internet and the PlantUML docs for the answer, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Oh sorry, it's indeed written in the PlantUML documentation (https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta)

The answer is: `end`

Comment: You can well mark your own answer as correct.